# Why do i get discord js command handler error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Ive tried implementing a command handler, so i can make embed commands because ive got a lot of errors while coding embeds in my index.js file and everybody in all tutorials uses command handlers. So anyways i followed the command step by step and now i get Errors.
This is the bot code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client({intents:["GUILDS","GUILD_MESSAGES"]});

const fs = require("fs");
var read_data = fs.readFileSync("./userdata.json");
var datafile = JSON.parse(read_data);

const levels_api = require("mee6-levels-api");

var bump_timeout = true;

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var eventFiles = fs.readdirSync("./events").filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of eventFiles){
  const event = require(`./events/${file}`);

  if(event.once){
    client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
  }
  else{
    client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
  }
}

app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", function() {
console.log("Listening on Port 3000");
});


client.on("message", message => {
  var msg_value = message.content.toLowerCase();
  var username = message.author.username;
  var id = message.author.id;
  var user_joined = new Date(message.author.joinedTimestamp).toLocaleDateString();
  if(msg_value.includes('hello') && msg_value.includes('bot') || msg_value.includes('hi') && msg_value.includes('bot')){
    message.channel.send("hi dad");
  }
  if(message.content === "!d bump" && bump_timeout==true){
    if(!datafile[id]){
      datafile[id] = {coins: 100};
      fs.writeFileSync("./userdata.json", JSON.stringify(datafile, null, 2));
      message.channel.send(`<@${id}> got 100 coins!`);
    }
    else{
      var chillcoins = Number(datafile[id].coins) + 100;
      message.channel.send(`<@${id}> got ${chillcoins} coins!`);
      datafile[id] = {coins: chillcoins};
      fs.writeFileSync("./userdata.json", JSON.stringify(datafile, null, 2));
    };
    bump_timeout = false;
    setTimeout(bump_switchtimeout, 72000000);
  };
  if(message.content.startsWith('!squid') && message.content.includes('bal')){
    var mentioned_user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.member.user;
    var mentioned_user_id = mentioned_user.id;
    if(!datafile[mentioned_user_id]){
      datafile[mentioned_user_id] = {coins: 0};
      fs.writeFileSync("./userdata.json", JSON.stringify(datafile, null, 2));
      message.channel.send(`<@${mentioned_user_id}> has 0 coins`);
    }
    else{
      var coins = Number(datafile[mentioned_user_id].coins);
      message.channel.send(`<@${mentioned_user_id}> has ${coins} coins`);
    }
  }
  if(msg_value == "!squid help"){
    const help_embed = new discord.MessageEmbed
      .setTitle("Squid bot Commands")
      .addFields(
            { name: 'Hi Bot', value: 'You greet our bot' },
            { name: '!squid help', value: 'You call the ambulance' },
            { name: '!d bump', value: 'Bumping the server will give you chillcoins', inline: true },
            { name: '!squid bal', value: 'This command displays your chillcoins', inline: true },
      );
    message.channel.send({embeds: [help_embed]});
  }

  
})

function bump_switchtimeout(){
  bump_timeout = true;
}

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("bot is ready");
  client.user.setActivity({name: "chilling", type: "PLAYING"});
})


client.login("token");
```

This is the error Message:

```
ReferenceError: commands is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\index.js:23:65)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:646:26)
    at Client.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:379:17)
    at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:362:10)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:189:14)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at WebSocketShard.checkReady (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:509:12)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:481:16)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Squidbot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:317:10)
```

Comment: well ... where IS it defined? certainly not in the code you posted

Comment: var eventFiles = fs.readdirSync("./events").filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of eventFiles){
  const event = require(`./events/${file}`);

  if(event.once){
    client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
  }
  else{
    client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
  }
}

Comment: no, I can see where you **use** `commands` ... where is it **defined**

Comment: It looks like you just copy pasted something.. Don't use `comands` but im almost sure you need to use client in your exec . `event.execute(client, ...args))`

Comment: @JaromandaX i didnt defined it anywhere

Comment: @squidguy - and that's what the error is telling you! So what did you want `commands` to be when you wrote the code?

Answer (score 0):

`commands` isn't defined anywhere, at least not in the code you posted so simply don't use a variable that doesn't exist

```js
// client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
```

```js
// client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args, commands));
client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
```